# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, npgsql, f#-data

Trying to use SQLTypeProvider with postgres I get the following errorwhen running

```
dotnet build
```

> error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider'
>   reported an error: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>   [/home/sashan/code/titan/src/Server/Server.fsproj]

my data provider is this:

```
type SQL = SqlDataProvider< 
                  ConnectionString = pg_dev_conn_string,
                  DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL,
                  UseOptionTypes = true >
```

If I change it to the following

```
type SQL = SqlDataProvider< 
              ConnectionString = pg_dev_conn_string,
              DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL,
              ResolutionPath = "/home/sashan/code/dotnet/2.1.500/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe/4.5.1/lib/netcoreapp2.0",
              UseOptionTypes = true >
```

The error goes away but I don't understand why. The fix seems really weird. Why should I have to point it to a file outside of my project? Shouldn't the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll be somewhere in one of project's subdirectories where the compiler can find it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I ran into it today. I am using macOS. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with unity container and after updated this dll from Nuget my problem solved

Answer (score 5):

i fix it comenting in web.config the entry that contains 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Answer (score 3):

**Try it in CMD,**

> you can find gacutil in(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools>), and other installed frameworks in bin folder, try runs same commands for other '..\bin\NETFX x.x Tools' frameworks if necessary

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools>**

gacutil -i "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\tools\net472\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll"

Comment: It did not work for me, so finally I used the NuGet package manager to uninstall the problematic item and reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact cause of this problem (and other problems alike, which `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'...` But in my case the solution was:

- Reinstall the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` starting with all dependant packages.

Be sure you take note of the dependency tree (NuGet package name and version), you may need the information down the road.